# how to extract all countries geometry from Openstreet map dataset in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, gis, openstreetmap

I am using this query to extract the geometry of all countries using OSM, it works ok, but I am sure, it is creating a duplicated as I am using flag as a reference, some places have a flag, but they are not really countries

```
SELECT feature_type, osm_id, osm_timestamp, geometry,ar.key,ar.value,
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_features`,UNNEST(all_tags) ar
   where ('boundary', 'administrative') IN (SELECT (key, value) FROM UNNEST(all_tags))
   and(feature_type="polygon" or feature_type= "multipolygon")
   AND ('flag') IN (SELECT (key) FROM UNNEST(all_tags)) and ar.key="name" order by st_area(geometry) desc
```

sorry forget to say, some tags are missing, for example if you select admin_level = 2, countries like the USA get dropped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can a list of all countries and their geometries by merging 2 tables:

```sql
SELECT features.feature_type, features.osm_id
  , ARRAY(
     SELECT DISTINCT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST(features.all_tags||relations.all_tags)
     WHERE key IN('int_name', 'name')
     ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1 
  ) features
 , ROUND(ST_AREA(geometry)/1e6,1) area
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_features` AS features,
  `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_relations` AS relations
WHERE ('boundary','administrative') IN (SELECT (key,value) FROM UNNEST(features.all_tags))
AND ('admin_level','2') IN (SELECT (key,value) FROM UNNEST(relations.all_tags))
AND feature_type = 'multipolygon'
AND relations.id=SAFE_CAST(features.osm_id AS INT64)
ORDER BY area
```

[image]

([ref](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153934378))

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the two previous answers that are not working anymore.
Due to some enumeration type changes in GeoOpenStreet (like rename of multipolygon to multipolygons), and don't consider that flag is mandatory, but ISO code.

```
SELECT (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key = 'ISO3166-1:alpha2') as CountryISO2Code,
  geometry AS CountryGeometry,
  st_area(geometry) as CountryArea
FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_features`
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key = 'boundary' AND value = 'administrative')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key = 'admin_level' AND value = '2') 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key = 'ISO3166-1:alpha2') 
ORDER BY CountryArea DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative#National
admin_level = 2 describes countries.

So I tidied your query and added admin_level = 2 filter so that it only includes countries.

```
SELECT 
  feature_type, osm_id, osm_timestamp, geometry,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key = 'flag') as flag,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key = 'name') as name,
  st_area(geometry) as area
FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_features`
WHERE 
  feature_type in ("polygon", "multipolygon")
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key = 'boundary' AND value = 'administrative')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key = 'flag') 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key = 'admin_level' AND value = '2') 
ORDER BY area desc
```

For USA, I found that link that explains everything about USA..
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/United_States/Boundaries#National_boundary

You can see openstreetmap record for the USA here https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/148838#map=1/41/0
On the left side, there are all the features.

Also, you can find USA record in BigQuery with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_features`
where osm_id = '148838'
```

Even there is admin_level in openstreetmap record, it doesn't exist in BigQuery record. I don't know why, it may just be an old version.

So you can optimize your filters using the query above to include the USA.

Comment: actually, that's my issue, there is a bug in bigquery dataset, I know about USA because it has a big area, but how about other countries, how I can be sure that all countries are accounted for

Comment: It must be about BigQuery. I don't know how often is it updated, but the last update date is March 28th.
You may want to create an issue in BigQuery issue tracker.  You can ask it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%20status:open

Comment: there is an issue reported here already  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153934378

Comment: Check the answer I left - which fixes this issue with a JOIN