# USA and Russia Geometry extracted from Bigquery has a visual distortion

Tags: google-bigquery, gis

I am using this query to extract the geometries of all countries using BigQuery public dataset, see question here

[how to extract all countries geometry from Openstreet map dataset in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61268379/how-to-extract-all-countries-geometry-from-openstreet-map-dataset-in-bigquery)

I use R to draw the results 
[image]
I tried Kepler.GL and gave me the same results
[image]

Something is wrong with Russia and the USA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know little about R visualization, but what is probably happening is you getting WKT text from BigQuery, and feeding it to R, which has different assumptions.

Tthe issue is your R package probably treats WKT differently than BigQuery. WKT semantics depends on the spatial reference system (SRS) used, which could be geographic (non-projected, using sphere or ellipsoid) or projected (flat map). BigQuery uses geographic system, so edge between points A and B is the shortest geodesic path. Most visualization systems use projected coordinates, and assume flat map. Edge between A and B is shortest straight line on the flat map.

While this does not matter too much in many cases, it still does affect precision when you have long edges. But when an edge crosses anti-meridian (180 degree meridian) you get big problem. An edge between (-169, 66) (eastern edge of Russia) and say (176, 70) (a nearby point on Chukchi sea) is relatively short on the sphere, it crosses anti-meridian, and spans 15 degrees longitude. But the same edge on flat map span 145 degrees longitude and crosses most of the map! These are the long near-horizontal lines you see.

What should you do?

- If R has a packet that supports geographic SRS (it is sometime an option to use geodesic edges), you could try it.
- Or you can also let BigQuery convert geography from geographic SRS to flat map, that R would understand, using `ST_AsGeoJson` function. GeoJson is defined on flat map, so BigQuery `ST_AsGeoJson` converts the semantics from geographic SRS to flat map SRS. You then visualize GeoJson string instead of WKT string in R.

`ST_AsGeoJson` does a lot of work, to make result conformant to GeoJson spec and flat map. It splits parts of geography that lay east and west of anti-meridian, so you don't get edges that cross it. It also approximates geodesic edges with flat map edges. But it makes visualization system much easier.