# Get centroid coordinates of a given country in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, geolocation, geography

In BigQuery, given a country in ISO-2 code I need to get its centroids coordinates (lat and long).
There is a way to do this?
Looking into the [geography functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions) of BQ I did not find a way.

Comment: Hi @Ire00! If my answer addressed your question, consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_features` table from BigQuery public datasets to calculate the centroids of countries. The inner query is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68272690/15745884) from Stack Overflow. Consider the below query and output.

```sql
SELECT -- Extract country code, lat and long
 CountryISO2Code,
 ST_X(centroid) AS longitude,
 ST_Y(centroid) AS latitude
FROM (SELECT (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(all_tags)
   WHERE key = 'ISO3166-1:alpha2') AS CountryISO2Code,
     ST_CENTROID(geometry) centroid -- calculate the centroid with the geometry values
   FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_features`
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key='boundary' AND value= 'administrative')
     AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key='admin_level' AND value = '2')
     AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key='ISO3166-1:alpha2'))
WHERE CountryISO2Code="IN" -- country code to filter the output
```

**Output of the above query**
[image]

Please note that there are some country codes that are not available in the table. Also, [OSM dataset in BigQuery](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/openstreetmap/geo-openstreetmap) itself is produced as a public good by volunteers, and there are no guarantees about data quality.

I also found some community-maintained data from Github like [this one](https://gist.github.com/tadast/8827699) which can be imported into BigQuery and is ready-to-use.